# Unable to get desired output from relative/absolute positioning in css

Tags: html, css

**Background**: I am creating a chat-room page in html/css. The div `rm-container` contains an area where messages are displayed(div class `rm-messages`), an area to input the message, as well as a div which contains all the users currently in the chatroom (`rm-users`).

**Problem**: I would like `rm-users` to be on the top right of `rm-container`, but I am unable to get it to work. I followed the tutorial on positioning from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and in my css, changing `rm-container` position to relative, and `rm-users` position to absolute, yet I am unable to get the desired result. Instead, what I get is `rm-users` it is below `rm-messages`, as would be expected if the default position had not been changed. I have attached both the css and html files below.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300);

body {

 background-color: #F0F0E6;
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0
}


.rm-name {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-top:15px;
 text-align:center;
 max-width:100px;
 
}

.userbox {

 border: 1px solid black;
 max-width:300px;
 padding-bottom:50px;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-top:15px;
}


.rm-container {

 position:relative;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px groove black; 
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 40px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 padding-bottom: 100px
 
}

.rm-messages {

 position:static;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin-top:10px;
 max-width: 700px;
 margin-left:15px;
 height:400px;
}

.rm-users {
 position:absolute;
 margin-top: 15px;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin-right: 15px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>room-name</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/room.css">
</head>

<body>

 <img src="something" class="chat_room_pic">
 <div class="rm-userbox">
  <img src="something" class="userPic">
  <h3 class="userName">Username | <a href=#> logout | </a><a href="#"> more chatrooms</a></h3>  
 </div>
 
 <div class="rm-container"> 
 <div id="rm-name"> room-name </div>
  
  <div class="rm-messages">
   <ul class="messages">
    <li>
     <div class="msgbox">
      <div class="pic"><img src="something>">Username </div>
      <div class="msg"><p>Hello there!</p></div>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="rm-users">
   <ul class="users">
    <li><img src="something">
  </div>
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `top: -70px` to .rm-users

```
.rm-users {
border: 1px groove black;
height: 50px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 15px;
overflow: scroll;
position: absolute;
top: -70px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: That worked, but cant accept an answer before 10 minutes. Do you know why top works, but margin-top does not?

Comment: Well when you set absolute position on some element you are positioning that element relatively to parent element that has position relative with `top` `bottom` `left` `right`.

Comment: So if you set `top: 0` and `left: 0` that absolute element will be in top left corner of relative parent element or if you set `bottom: 0` and `right: 0` that absolute element will be in bottom right corner

Comment: Thank you, that really helped (:

Comment: I am glad i could help :)